# make hot-questions configurable

Tags: feature-request

It would be really nice if hot-questions can be made configurable, or a new tab added next to hot-questions say "related-questions"  that will fetch related questions based on include and exclude tags  from all sites and show it in one place.

Or something similar already exists ?

**EDIT:** stackExchange Popup

[image: stackExchange Popup]

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by "hot questions"?

Comment: If you click on stackExchange icon on top left side it opens a popup I was referring to hot-questions in there

Comment: @Cody It's that damn Hansel!  He's so hot right now!

Comment: @downvoter I will definitely appriciate the reason for down vote, if you can give one that is  !!!

Comment: Reason for downvotes is here: [meta-faq#vote-differences]

Comment: @Daniel: Not sure who Hansel is, but there's a ["hot" tab](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) on the homepage, too. Sometimes it'll randomly show things I consider to be questions (getting rarer nowadays, though).

Comment: cheers cody, which (all) in particular ?

Comment: The highlighted part at the very top... It talks about why downvotes here on Meta are different, *especially* for questions tagged `[feature-request`. They mean people disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Disagree.

I think that [Hot questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) tab was made to select the highlights of last few days, some chart of the last questions, and not to select high activity posts in specific tag.

You can filter the questions, and after that sort them as you wish - votes, views or whatever you want.

Comment: He's talking about the Stack Exchange hot questions that you see when you expand the menu at the top left, not the hot questions tab on SO.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard Ooops.

Comment: VMAtm, I Think you are refering "Top Questions " and "hot" tab in SO. Will add a screenshot to make it clear